# How can I have multiple functions?

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to javaScript so my code may be a bit wrong. I was wondering how i can have multiple javaScript `functions` that actually work one below the other. As I can only get one function to work.

I dont know if it is the right layout but i'd really appericate if you can help me out, thank you.

Here is the code:

```
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        "use strict";    
         const l_form = document.getElementById('bookingForm');  
         l_form.onchange = calculateTotal;  


        function calculateTotal() {
            let l_totalPrice = 0;  

            const l_item = l_form.querySelectorAll('div.item');  
            const l_itemCount = l_item.length;  

            for (let t_i = 0; t_i < l_itemCount; t_i++) {

                  const t_item = l_item[t_i];  
                  const t_checkbox = t_item.querySelector('input[data-price][type=checkbox]');
                  if (t_checkbox.checked) {

                    l_totalPrice += parseFloat(t_checkbox.dataset.price);
                  }
            }
        l_form.total.value = l_totalPrice;

    }
     });

      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      function enableBtn() {
        const getTermsChbk =  document.querySelector('termsChkbx');
        const getSubmit = document.querySelector('submit');
        if (getTermsChbk.checked) {
            text.style.color = "black";
            getSubmit.disabled = false;
        }
        else {
            getSubmit.disabled = true;
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you had a syntax error. Here it is fixed:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    "use strict";


    const l_form = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
    l_form.onchange = calculateTotal;


    function calculateTotal() {
        let l_totalPrice = 0;

        const l_item = l_form.querySelectorAll('div.item');
        const l_itemCount = l_item.length;

        for (let t_i = 0; t_i < l_itemCount; t_i++) {

            const t_item = l_item[t_i];
            const t_checkbox = t_item.querySelector('input[data-price][type=checkbox]');
            if (t_checkbox.checked) {

                l_totalPrice += parseFloat(t_checkbox.dataset.price);
            }
        }
        l_form.total.value = l_totalPrice;

    }
});

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    function enableBtn() {
        const getTermsChbk = document.querySelector('termsChkbx');
        const getSubmit = document.querySelector('submit');
        if (getTermsChbk.checked) {
            text.style.color = "black";
            getSubmit.disabled = false;
        } else {
            getSubmit.disabled = true;
        }
    }
});
```

But your `enableBtn` function will never run from what you've posted here.

Comment: I don't see how your version will work either... it just defines a function and never calls it

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be a simple problem with your curly braces {}. Make sure each function is separate and self contained, variables are within the scope of the function you want to use them in, and make sure your function returns something (actually not necessary in javascript but it definitely helps with debugging). Hope this helps and happy coding!